# how to set profile-specific applicaiton.properties(spring boot) outside war(jboss)?

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, jboss7.x

I have spring boot application that I am running in jboss(instead of tomcat).
I am using spring profile for loading environment specific application.properties.

Profile specific application{env}.properties is working fine when placed under "src/main/resources/" however, it is not working when placed externally.

I tried setting property in jboss standalone.xml but application fails to start in jboss.

```
<property name="spring.config.location" value="C:/Dev/config/rt" />
```

Please suggest how to load the environment specific application.properties files that are not placed inside the war file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was expecting spring to pick the profile specific file from the folder but looks like that's not the case.

It appears that spring.config.location needs to have the absolute  file location instead of folder location. so, updated spring.config.location in standalone.xml and it worked :

```
<property name="spring.config.location" value="C:/Dev/config/rt/application-dev.properties" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide externalized configuration file using below command when you are initially starting the application,

```
java -jar <your-jar-name.jar> --spring.config.location=<path><external property>
```

example :

```
java -jar mySample.jar --spring.config.location=./application-external.properties
```

[read more](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: this works with the standalone jar but I am deploying it as war on JBOSS

Answer (score 0):

Generally it was picked very easily when it's placed under the 'src/main/resources' folder. suppose you have to different files for profiles like - application-dev.properties and application-prod.properties, you need to set only the current working profile in the application.properties like

spring.profiles.active=dev

and it will be picked easily. If it's doesn't you need to create a workaround by creating  a new bat or sh file like run.bat and run.sh in the bin folder of the jboss and pass the file location like

--spring.config.location=

The complete command to be added in the bat/sh file will be

```
 java -jar appName.jar --spring.config.name=application-dev --spring.config.location=c:/Dev/application-dev.properties
```

Comment: this works with the standalone jar but I am deploying it as war on JBOSS

Comment: create a new profile in jboss after coping the default profile, rename the run.bat or run.sh to start.bat and start.sh
run the profile with nohup 
 $JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh -c $PROFILE_NAME
and in the run.conf file in the bin directory pass these values as part of 

 JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.config.name=application-dev  -Dspring.config.location=c:/Dev/application-dev.properties